# Difference between ''may'' and ''may well''

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between *may* and *may well* in following sentences? Besides, which sentence says it is more likely to rain?

1. It may rain.
2. It may well rain.

Comment: Often "may well" is simply used for poetic effect.  I think I hear it in the context of "That may well be true, but ..." than in any other, and in that case it's clearly not intended to concede a higher probability.

Answer (score 6):

> It may rain.

This means that rain is a possibility; it may happen or it may not.

> It may well rain.

This means that rain is a possibility, and that the speaker thinks that there is good reason for it to occur.

For example:

> You'd better bring an umbrella; it may well rain today.

---

Dictionary references:

[Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well):

> **may well**
>   10b. in all likelihood: *indeed it may well be true*

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/may-well):

> **may well**
>   If you say that something may well happen, you mean that it is likely to happen:
>   *She may well not want to travel alone.*

Comment: There's another "may well" definition on the M-W page; I'll edit it into my answer later today as the page started playing sound and I'm at a work computer right now.